# How to save two array list in one single row in table

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

How to save two array list in a single row in table?

I have try to foreach every array but I just want to know how to save the array in single row in table just see the picture below. i don't want to have an null value. because this function is like single file that reference in job_orders.

```
    $date = $request->get('date');
    $client_name = $request->get('client_name');
    $address = $request->get('address');
    $service_date = $request->get('service_date');
    $service_time = $request->get('service_time');
    $contact_person = $request->get('contact_person');
    $vehicle = $request->get('vehicles');
    $services = $request->input('services');
    $supplies = $request->input('supplies');
    $accessories = $request->input('accessories');
    $miscellaneous = $request->input('miscellaneous');
    DB::begintransaction();
    try{
        $data = [
            'vehicle_id' => $request->get('vehicle_id'),
            'service_date' => $request->get('service_date'),
            'service_time' => $request->get('service_time'),
            'discount' => $request->get('discount'),
            'total' => $request->get('total'),
            'technician' => $request->get('technician'),
            'assistant' => $request->get('assistant'),
        ];
        $joborders = $this->joborders->create($data);
        if($services !== null){
            foreach($services as $service) {
                $data = [
                    'job_order_id' => $joborders->id,
                    'service_name' => $service['service_name'],
                    'service_qty' => $service['service_qty'],
                    'service_cost' => $service['service_cost'],
                ];
                $this->items->create($data);
            }
        }
        if($supplies !== null ){
            foreach($supplies as $supply){
                $data = [
                    'job_order_id' => $joborders->id,
                    'supply_name' => $supply['supply_name'],
                    'supply_qty' => $supply['supply_qty'],
                    'supply_cost' => $supply['supply_cost'],
                ];
                $this->items->create($data);
            }
        }
        if($accessories !== null){
            foreach($accessories as $accessory){
                $data = [
                    'job_order_id' => $joborders->id,
                    'accessory_name' => $accessory['accessory_name'],
                    'accessory_qty' => $accessory['accessory_qty'],
                    'accessory_cost' => $accessory['accessory_cost'],
                ];
                $this->items->create($data);
            }
        }
        if($miscellaneous !== null)
        {
            foreach($miscellaneous as $misc){
                $data = [
                    'job_order_id' => $joborders->id,
                    'misc_name' => $misc['miscellaneous_name'],
                    'misc_qty' => $misc['miscellaneous_qty'],
                    'misc_cost' => $misc['miscellaneous_cost'],
                ];
                $this->items->create($data);
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: What's the error? You should also post your code in full. We have no idea what `$joborders` is or even `$this->items`.

Comment: sir i edited my questions just for clarify

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to achieve: Your loop indicate that they may be more then 1 `accessory` (for example) and then it make sense to insert to different rows.. So what is your desire outcome?

Comment: i have 4 different array list. as you can see in my code  i go for foreach every array list and the outcome of my code are image below. i want to achieve is just to save the 4 different array list in single line row in table.

Comment: and every same index of array is save in singe line row in table so that i cannot get the null value in my table

Comment: You can do something like `$res= array_map(null, $services ,$supplies, $accessories, $miscellaneous);` and then loop on `$res` with index

Comment: thanks buddy now i get this foreach ($res as $estimate){
                $data = [
                    'job_order_id' => $joborders->id,
                    'service_name' => $estimate[0]['service_name'],
                    'service_qty' => $estimate[0]['service_qty'],
                    'service_cost' => $estimate[0]['service_cost'],
                    'supply_name' => $estimate[1]['supply_name'],
                    'supply_qty' => $estimate[1]['supply_qty'],
                    'supply_cost' => $estimate[1]['supply_cost'],